# C++ sorting unordered_map or map by value

Tags: c++

I have python code that I am trying to convert to C++ equivalent.

```
dict1 = {i:(val1,val2,val3)} 
dict_sorted = sorted(dict1.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1][2])
```

This will sort dictionary `dict1`  by `val3` and stored in `dict_sorted` (which is not a dictionary).

In c++, I have `std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<double>> dict1`, or `map` similar to above. Vector will have `val1,val2,val3`. How can I sort this unordered map using `val3`?

Comment: An **unordered** map isn't sorted (ordered). It's a hashed key-value container. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: dictionary is also not sorted. As described in question, trying to sort based on value.

Comment: Your Python code isn't making a sorted `dict`, to be clear. It's making a brand new `list` of two `tuple`s, sorted by the third element of the second element of each `tuple` (the "value" when it was a `dict`). So for equivalent C++, you'd be making a new sorted `vector` of `pair`s sorted on the third element of each `pair`'s `.second`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [I noted in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56553458/c-sorting-unordered-map-or-map-by-value/56553553#comment99688311_56553458), the Python code is making a sorted `list` of two-`tuple`s, sorting based on the third element of the second element in each `tuple` (the result is not a `dict`). For equivalent C++ code, you're replacing `dict` with `std::unordered_map`, `list` with `std::vector`, and the two-`tuple` with `std::pair`; to precisely match Python's `sorted` results, you'd want to use `std::stable_sort` for the sorting.

So something like (where `dict1` is your `unordered_map`):

```
using kv_pair = std::pair<int, std::vector<double>>;

std::vector<kv_pair> dict_sorted;
dict_sorted.reserve(dict1.size());
for (const auto& kv : dict1) {
    dict_sorted.emplace_back(kv.first, kv.second);
}
std::stable_sort(std::begin(dict_sorted), std::end(dict_sorted),
                 [](const kv_pair& a, const kv_pair& b) { return a.second[2] < b.second[2]; });
```